# Limits of Integration Trig, Mag Field Infinite Length Wire

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I don't understand how the limits of integration should be defined when doing basic integrals of trig functions. It seems like it's an arbitrary decision, I don't understand it.

Here's the set up: For the field near a long straight wire carrying a current I, show the Biot-Savart law gives the same result as Ampere's law.

[image]

Now intuitively, for me at least, with the way that theta is defined, I would view the angle as becoming smaller as y moves toward negative infinity. So the limits of integration make sense in that regards. But then the cosine doesn't make sense anymore. As y becomes more negative, which corresponds to an angle between 0 and pi/2, then cosine should always be positive. But because cos=adj/hyp, then cos=y/r, and y would be negative, even though the corresponding angle is between 0 and pi/2?

I know I'm misunderstanding something fundamental, hopefully somebody can help me so I can move on. I've been struggling with this for so long because it's easy enough to arbitrarily assign limits to get the answer you're looking for, but I want to know the right way.

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.stackexchange.  A couple of things I'd recommend you to consider is to check out this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting your questions on the stack exchange websites.  The other thing too is that this question might be better suited for the physics.SE site.  Presumably the current density is $\mu$ pointing in the $+\hat{y}$ direction?

Comment: yes, the current density is in the y direction. I understand the physics of the problem, I am not understanding how the limits of integration are defined with respect to the coordinate system. I am not understanding why my book is telling me to use a certain interval that is contradicting. but if I integrate, treating -y as pi when it approaches infinity, I don't get the right answer. My reasoning is flawed somewhere. Is it that I am supposed to treat the positive y-axis as the origin of a unit circle?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the way to approach these problems is to avoid using the trigonometric symbols and convert them simply into cartesian coordinates.  The main way to approach this is to set up the Biot-Savart integral:

$$
\textbf{B}(P) \;\; =\;\; \frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin\theta dy}{R^2 + y^2} (-\hat{\textbf{z}}).
$$

We use the substitution $\sin \theta = \frac{R}{\sqrt{R^2 + y^2}}$, which we can accomplish by just recalling that $\sin\theta = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$.  Making this substitution our integral becomes

$$
\textbf{B}(P) \;\; =\;\; -\frac{\mu_0 IR}{4\pi}\hat{\textbf{z}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{(R^2 +y^2)^{3/2}}.
$$

While this integral may look intimidating at first the trig substitution $y = R\tan u$ will simplify things considerably.  Observe first that we can change the limits of integration to $-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}$, and subsequently obtain

\begin{eqnarray*}
\textbf{B}(P) & = & -\frac{\mu_0IR}{4\pi}\hat{\textbf{z}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{R\sec^2u}{R^3 \sec^3u} du \\
& = & -\frac{\mu_0I}{4\pi R}\hat{\textbf{z}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos u du.
\end{eqnarray*}

In general I would recommend getting rid of the initial trigonemetric symbol which will arise from the angle the current vector makes with the displacement vector, and then generally after that your integral will be sufficiently complicated to require a trig substitution.